# Can't figure out join statement in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to figure out how to execute the following sql join statement in Django without resorting to just raw sql. Is there a way to do it?

```
Select * from playertable, seasontable where player.id = season.player_id
```

Here are my models. Just to clarify, I used abbreviated table names in the above query for clarify

```
class Player(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=3)

class PlayerSeason(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    games_played = models.IntegerField()
    goals = models.IntegerField()
    assists = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
    plusminus = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pim = models.IntegerField()
    ppg = models.IntegerField()
    shg = models.IntegerField()
    gwg = models.IntegerField()
    otg = models.IntegerField()
    shots = models.IntegerField()
    shooting_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    toi = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sftg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    face_off = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

How should I do this with a Django `QuerySet`?

Comment: Where is your Season model? If you want all the players for a season just do `season.player_set.all()`

Comment: Are you trying to get in one query all players and all the seasons? or from one player do you want to get their seasons?

Comment: I want to get all the seasons associated with a specific player, and then blow that up so I can do that with all the players

Comment: and the season model is called PlayerSeason, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @F.C. put that in an answer and I'll give it to you, that's pretty much exactly what I needed to do (see edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you wanted to do was to get all the players associated with a given season you could make use of [Django's backwards relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

When you use a ForeignKeyField to a model, in this case Season, the that model instances get an attribute which allows you to get a queryset of all the related objects.

In your example you could use `season.player_set.all()`.

You can pass an optional parameter `related_name` to the `ForeignKeyField` that allows you to change the name of the season attribute.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to do it?

No. Django's ORM deals with one model at a time, and you are getting columns from two tables. Perform a query on either of the models and then access the appropriate field to get the related model.

Comment: Please explain your -1 please.  I was under this impression too, perhaps the voter could clarify?